# Implementing a simple jQuery autocomplete in Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I'm trying to implement a simple jQuery autocomplete in Rails 4. However, there are several problems with my current implementation. Namely, these are:

1. All results are always being listed.
2. Autocomplete list is not being cached on first request (multiple requests being made).
3. The terms are not being popped from the original list and appended, as I would expect.

Here is my code:

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui/autocomplete
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

**application.css**

```
*= require font-awesome
*= require jquery-ui/autocomplete
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
```

**articles.js**

```
var cache, complete, extractLast, split;
split = function(val) {
  return val.split(/,\s*/);
};

extractLast = function(term) {
  return split(term).pop();
};

cache = {};

complete = function() {
  $("input#article_person_list").bind("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }).autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: function(request, response) {
      var term;
      term = request.term;
      reuqest.term;
      if (term in cache) {
        response(cache[term]);
        return;
      }
      $.getJSON("/peopletags.json", request, function(data, status, xhr) {
        cache[term] = data;
        response(data);
      });
    },
    search: function() {
      var term;
      term = extractLast(this.value);
      if (term.length < 2) {
        return false;
      }
    },
    focus: function() {
      return false;
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      var terms;
      terms = split(this.value);
      terms.pop();
      terms.push(ui.item.value);
      terms.push("");
      this.value = terms.join(", ");
      return false;
    }
  });
};

$(document).ready(complete);
$(document).on('page:load', complete);
```

**articles_controller.rb**

```
def autocomplete_people
  @people = Article.all.collect {|tag| tag.person_list }.flatten.uniq.sort
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render(:json => @people)}
  end
end
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
var complete, extractLast, split;

split = function(val) {
  return val.split(/,\s*/);
};

extractLast = function(term) {
  return split(term).pop();
};

var cache = false;

complete = function() {
  $("input#article_person_list").bind("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      var term = extractLast(request.term);
      if (cache) {
        var terms = cache.filter(function(val) {
                return val.indexOf(term) !== -1
            });
        response( terms );
        console.log(cache);
        return;
      }
      else {
        $.getJSON("/peopletags.json", {
          term: term
        },
        function( data, status, xhr ) {
          cache = data;
            var terms = cache.filter(function(val) {
                return val.indexOf(term) !== -1
            });
        response( terms );
        });
      }
    },
    search: function() {
      var term;
      term = extractLast(this.value);
      if (term.length < 1) {
        return false;
      }
    },
    focus: function() {
      return false;
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      var terms;
      terms = split(this.value);
      terms.pop();
      terms.push(ui.item.value);
      terms.push("");
      this.value = terms.join(", ");
      return false;
    }
  });
};

$(document).ready(complete);
$(document).on('page:load', complete);
$(document).on('page:keyup', complete);
```